# How to cast List<Class<?>> to concrete type?

Tags: java, casting, generic-list

Given the following code snipppet:

```
public class ContentProvider {

    public static List<Class<?>> getProducts() {
        return getContent(42, Product.class);
    }

    private static List<Class<?>> getContent(int id, Class<?> contentType) {
        // Generic content retrieval.
    }

}
```

How can cast the return value of `getContent` so that `getProducts()` returns `List<Product>`?

Comment: With `List<Class<?>>` you are returning a `List` of `Class` instances. Is that what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a generic method for this:

```
public class ContentProvider {

    public static List<Product> getProducts() {
        return getContent(42, Product.class);
    }

    private static <T> List<T> getContent(int id, Class<T> contentType) {
        // Generic content retrieval.
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah it would be fine. Just add code to create a `List<T>` inside and return it.

Comment: @Marcelo Thanks, this works. Please add that `Product` needs to `extends Object`.

Comment: @JJD Every class extends `Object`, not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Marcelo I use a POJO for `Product` which did not extend `Object`. Just to mention for others.